# Left Menu Tabs Control in Windows Forms Application How can i get it? Its available in current controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

i am building a C# application, i have explored its all controls but i cant find the left menu style which i usually see in software applications for example visual studio, i am attaching the image of what i need.[image]
Please let me know how can i use it in my forms. I have used a tab menu control in visual studio, but it is not what i required, its tabs are vertical, but i want the exact like i shown in attachment. I think it requires some reference to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that control is available, which means you would have to make one yourself.  Here is a link from someone that made one.  I haven't tried it: [Visual Studios "My Project" Tab Control](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=580655)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a control in the ToolBox by default. But you could create one for you.

1. Creat a user controller.
2. Added a [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) and set Dock.Fill.
3. Add a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx) to the Left panel. Add buttons or labels as you wish and implement the click event.